# PHP: How find the full index of a specific value in a multidimensional array

Tags: php, multidimensional-array

I have this array

```
$languages = array (
    'de' => 
        array (
            'FIRSTNAME' => 'Vorname',
            'SURNAME' => 'Nachname'
        ),
    'en' => 
        array ( 
            'FIRSTNAME' => 'Firstname',
            'SURNAME' => 'Surname'
        )
 );
```

and I am trying to get the full index (full key) of `$languages` by using the value of `SURNAME` for example.

**Example: Looking for 'Firstname' should return `$languages['en']['FIRSTNAME']`**

I tried `array_search` combined with `array_column` but in fact I don't know the "column" to look for

```
array_search($value, array_column($array_to_search_in, 'column'));
```

I also found a solution with `array_walk_recursive` but only with key comparison, not by value.

```
array_walk_recursive($languages, function($v, $k, $u) use (&$values){
    if($k == $value) {
        $values[] = $v;
    }
},  $values );
```

Any help is as always highly appreciated!! 
Thanks!

Comment: In your `array_walk_recursive()` code, try swapping the test to be `$v == $value` and `$values[] = $k` (you will also need to add `$value` to your `use` clause.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. It is getting close but it only returns `Array
(
    [0] => FIRSTNAME
)`. I need also the first "key" which is "en"

Comment: Is your array structure always the same as above (although you may have more options at both levels)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Never worked with `array_walk_recursive`, but IMO you can apply a basic recursive function.
This would loop over the data. If value is same as search key, then we return an array which has the current key. If parent recursive call receives an array with size more than 0, we add current parent key to return result as well.

```
<?php

function search($data,$search_key){
    foreach($data as $key => $value){
        if(is_array($value)){
            $result = search($value,$search_key);
            if(count($result) > 0){
                $result[] = $key;
                return $result;
            }
        }else if($value == $search_key){
            return [$key];
        }
    }

    return [];
}
```

**Demo:** https://3v4l.org/Drfpv